# Argument Exception Was Caught

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have a linq query which I use to get data from the DB.

And I have join two tables in the query.

Here is my database structure..
[image: DB Structure]

I need to get Customer with primary telephone number and default shipping address.
And this is my query..

```
    var customer=UnitOfWork.DbContext.Set<Domain.BoundedContext.ScreenPop.Entities.Customer>()
.Include(x => x.CustomerPhoneNumbers.Select(p => p.IsPrimary == true))
.Include(x => x.ShippingAddresses.Select(s => s.IsDefault == true))
.Where(c => c.CustomerId == customerQuery.CustomerId).FirstOrDefault();
```

But it gives me this error..

```
The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. 
    Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
```

How can I get these information by using those three tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The includes are just a way to say what navigation properties/tables you want included. Try this

```
var customer=UnitOfWork.DbContext.Set<Domain.BoundedContext.ScreenPop.Entities.Customer>()
.Include(x => x.CustomerPhoneNumbers)
.Include(x => x.ShippingAddresses)
.Where(c => c.CustomerId == customerQuery.CustomerId).FirstOrDefault();
```

and then just get the phone number and address you want

```
var phonenumber = customer.CustomerPhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.IsPrimary);
var address = customer.ShippingAddresses.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.IsDefault);
```